# How would you convert this recursive solution to an iterative one?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

We want to create the iterative function starting from the corresponding recursive.
What the function has to do is go through the non-binary tree, which has numbers as nodes and recreate the sentences.

I am creating strings using an imaginary graph.
I take the data from the list of dictionaries, already sorted.

Every time I do list_dictionary [1:], when this list is empty, I close the recursion.
I start with 2 and see the corresponding value list in the dictionary, so i read the numbers and (recursion) go through the tree at this step, building the sentence.

I have this list of dictionary:

```
dict_in_ilist = [{2: [['hack', 1], ['service', 3], ['process', 4]]}, 
              {1: [['CPU', 7], ['light', 6]], 
               3: [['you', 8]], 4: [['value', 5]]}, 
              {7: [['pentest', 5]], 6: [['phone', 2]], 
               8: [['CPU', 1]], 5: [['key', 8]]}, 
              {5: [['crisis', 2]], 2: [['date', 4]], 
               1: [['goal', 3]], 8: [['clark', 1]]}, 
              {2: [['crack', 1]], 4: [['del', 7]], 
               3: [['london', 6]], 1: [['canc', 5]]}, 
              {1: [['clock', 6]], 7: [["sound", 6]], 
                   6: [['palace', 8]], 5: [['packer', 8]]}]
start_number = 2
```

Here there is the tree:

```
 2
    1   
        7
            5
                2
                    1
        6
            2
                1
                    3
    3
        8
            1
                6
                    2   
    4
        5
            2
                1
                    7
```

so the paths of tree are:

```
2,1,7,5,2,1
2,1,6,2,1,3
2,3,8,1,6,2
2,4,5,2,1,7
```

The recursive function:

```
def do_sentences(dict_in_ilist,number,result,sentence=""):
    if len(dict_in_ilist) == 0:
        return sentence
    if number in dict_in_ilist[0].keys():
        for start in dict_in_ilist[0][number]:
            result.append(do_sentences(dict_in_ilist[1:],start[1],result,sentence+" "+ start[0]))
    return(())
```

The output:

```
result = []
do_sentences(dict_in_ilist,start_number,result)
result = set(result)
result.remove(())
print(result)

{'service you CPU goal london palace', 'hack light phone date del sound', 'hack CPU pentest crisis crack clock', 'process value key clark canc packer'}
```

Comment: I am extremely confused by what your function is doing. Please explain!!

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: I'm also slightly confused of what you try to achieve ...

Comment: I need of a iterative function that return all path of the three, to complete all sentences. The dictionary can be rewrite in form of tree, but i want a function that takes this particul input